# Load remote image from API call into img tag

Tags: html, linkedin-api

Hi I am retrieving linkedin user data including their image.

But I am unable to load the profile image in a simple HTML img tag.

LinkedIn test image below

```
https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQHiiNx4DLi0iQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0/1621018841058?e=1686787200&v=beta&t=ixCXfEW-By906xKCd67vHaqz1B08E54MU79TqX21G0E
```

However I cant add this to an img "src". I figured it is because this is an API call

I have tried using fetch like below:

```
<img src={fetch (`https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQHiiNx4DLi0iQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0/1621018841058?e=1686787200&v=beta&t=ixCXfEW-By906xKCd67vHaqz1B08E54MU79TqX21G0E`)}>
          </img>
```

But this doesnt work.
**How do i load images from an API request such as LinkIn?**

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no such thing as a closing image tag `</img>`

Answer (score 0):

To load the image in your HTML img tag, you need to fetch the image data from the API endpoint and convert it to a data URL format that can be used as the src attribute of the img tag. Example using JavaScript:

```js
fetch('https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQHiiNx4DLi0iQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0/1621018841058?e=1686787200&v=beta&t=ixCXfEW-By906xKCd67vHaqz1B08E54MU79TqX21G0E')
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(img); // replace with your own code to add the image to your page
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```